# Segmentation Fault Error Dealing with Matrices (Arrays)

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to reference a 2D array object I've constructed, but for whatever reason I'm getting a segmentation fault and I'm having trouble figuring out the cause. So far I've deduced that the error lies in my `operator<<` function, but I can't figure out what to change.

main.cpp:

```
int main() {    

My_matrix m1(3, 2);
cout << "Before" << endl;
m1(0,0) = 1; //causes segfault
cout << "After" << endl;
m1(0,1) = 2; //causes segfault
m1(1,0) = 3; //causes segfault
m1(1,1) = 4; //causes segfault
m1(2,0) = 5; //causes segfault
m1(2,1) = 6; //causes segfault
cout << "Checkpoint 1" << endl;
My_matrix m2(); //works
cout << "Checkpoint 2" << endl;

cout << m1.number_of_rows() << endl; //works

cout << "Checkpoint 3" << endl;
cout << m1; //Segfault
cout << "Checkpoint 4" << endl;

cout << m1; //Segfault
cout << "Checkpoint 5" << endl;
cout << m2; //Segfault
cout << "Checkpoint 6" << endl;

}
```

My_matrix.cpp:

```
#include "My_matrix.h"
#include <stdexcept>

My_matrix::My_matrix()
{
  n = 0;
  m = 0;
  ptr = nullptr;
}

My_matrix::My_matrix(int n1, int m1)
{
  n = n1;
  m = m1;
  ptr = new int*[n];
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      ptr[i] = new int[m];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
          ptr[i][j] = 0;
      }
  }
}

My_matrix::My_matrix(const My_matrix& mat)
{
  this->n = mat.n;
  this->m = mat.m;

  ptr = new int*[n];
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      ptr[i] = new int[m];
  }

  //----- copy elements over to new matrix -----//
  for (int i = 0; i < mat.n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < mat.m; j++) {
          this->ptr[n][m] = mat.ptr[n][m];
      }
  }
}

My_matrix::~My_matrix()
{
  clear();
}

My_matrix& My_matrix::operator=(const My_matrix& mat)
{
  clear();

  this->n = mat.n;
  this->m = mat.m;

  ptr = new int*[n];
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      ptr[i] = new int[m];
  }

  //----- copy elements over -----//
  for (int i = 0; i < mat.n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < mat.m; j++) {
          this->ptr[n][m] = mat.ptr[n][m];
      }
  }
}

int My_matrix::number_of_rows() const
{
  return n;
}

int My_matrix::number_of_columns() const
{
  return m;
}

int* My_matrix::operator()(int i) const
{
  return ptr[i];
}

int& My_matrix::operator()(int i, int j) const
{
  return ptr[n][m];
}

int& My_matrix::operator()(int i, int j)
{
  return ptr[n][m];
}

int& My_matrix::elem(int i, int j) const
{
  if (i < 0 || i >= n) throw out_of_range("Out of range");
  if (j < 0 || j >= m) throw out_of_range("Out of range");
  return ptr[n][m];
}

int& My_matrix::elem(int i, int j)
{
  if (i < 0 || i >= n) throw out_of_range("Out of range");
  if (j < 0 || j >= m) throw out_of_range("Out of range");
  return ptr[n][m];
}

void My_matrix::clear()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        delete[] ptr[i];
    }
    delete[] ptr;
    n = 0;
    m = 0;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const My_matrix& mat)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < mat.number_of_rows(); i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < mat.number_of_columns(); j++) {
          out << mat(i, j) << " "; //This line is the culprit ****
      }
      out << endl;
  }
  return out;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using raw pointers at all? That's not necessary with modern, .idiomatic c++ code

Comment: Unrelated, but `int& My_matrix::operator()(int i, int j) const` should be returning a `const int&`.

Comment: Part of the assignment dictates I use a double pointer. Also, thanks @scohe001

Comment: Unrelated: The mix of `this->` and `noThis` makes your code hard to read. e.g. in the constructor I see `this->n = ..` and `this->m = ..` then `ptr = ..` and so I'm assuming `ptr` isn't a member because you didn't say `this->ptr`. Consistency helps avoid bugs.

Comment: @McFizz _"Part of the assignment dictates ..."_ Bah! Blame your professor and kick them ass! That's silly and unnatural requirements. Nothing to do with _real world_ c++ programming.

Comment: @John3136 that's a good point. Not sure why I did that. I'll make that adjustment in my code. Do you think it's possible that's what's causing the issue?

Comment: @user9212993 How are C++ programmers supposed to learn low-level programming if they only use standard classes? We'll end up with no programmers who know how to implement the standard classes.

Comment: Have a second look at what you're returning in your `operator()`s and `elem()`s.

Comment: @user9212993 Should they force the students to use C when teaching about using pointers?

Comment: @McFizz Very doubtful that the use / non use of `this->` is related to the issue. It would only be a problem if you did have a local variable with the same name as a class member - then you need to make sure you know which one you are referencing.

Comment: `return ptr[n][m];` - interesting choice of indexes, since `[i][j]` are apparently what should have been used.

Comment: @Barmar Not at that stage of course!

Comment: If one is working towards a degree in Computer Science and they are striving to be a Professional, I feel that even ASM would be part of the curriculum... If people don't understand how the "circuits" work and the threshold of the current or voltage going through the gates that triggers the different types of instruction sets... then their degree to me would be a sugar coated piece of paper. It's kind of like a person becoming a mechanic but only knows how to change the tires.

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As hinted at by @WhozCraig and @O'Neil in the comments, I had a few typos in my code which referred to indices that were not in bounds of the matrix I had created. Rather than using the iterators/function arguments, I used `n` and `m`, which represent the *size* of the matrix, which is obviously one larger than the largest index. Examples include:

```
int& My_matrix::elem(int i, int j) const
{
  if (i < 0 || i >= n) throw out_of_range("Out of range");
  if (j < 0 || j >= m) throw out_of_range("Out of range");
  return ptr[n][m]; //<--- should be return ptr[i][j];
}
```

as well as

```
My_matrix::My_matrix(const My_matrix& mat)
{
  this->n = mat.n;
  this->m = mat.m;

  ptr = new int*[n];
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      ptr[i] = new int[m];
  }

  //----- copy elements over to new matrix -----//
  for (int i = 0; i < mat.n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < mat.m; j++) {
          this->ptr[n][m] = mat.ptr[n][m]; //<--- should be this->ptr[i][j] = mat.ptr[i][j];
      }
  }
}
```

By correcting these discrepancies my issue was resolved.

Comment: I find it interesting that this issue wasn't caused by improper usage of a pointer, as I had initially expected.